# How do i mimic copy and paste?

Tags: manipulate

I have an expression such as : `f[x] = x^2 * p[[1]]`

That is computed with DSolve, and I would like to insert that expression into:

```
Manipulate[Plot[ **INSERT HERE**   , {x, 0, 1}], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

When I simply Write:

```
Manipulate[Plot[ f[x]   , {x, 0, 1}], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

it does not identify the `p[[1]]` term correctly (as the x value of the locator), and cant produce a plot.

when i directly copy the term `x^2 * p[[1]]` and paste it into the plot, such as:

```
Manipulate[Plot[ x^2 * p[[1]]    , {x, 0, 1}], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

it identify the term correctly, and produces a plot.

I seek a function that would mimic this copy and paste, and I would appreciate if you can help me.

a simple example of the problam:

```
eq = {y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y[p[[1]]] == p[[2]]};
sol = DSolve[eq, y, x]
f[x_, p_] := y[x] /. sol[[1]]
f[x, p]
Manipulate[Plot[f[x, p] , {x, 0, p[[1]]}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},    
AspectRatio -> 1], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

That would not produce a plot.

Thank you!

Comment: This is probably a scoping issue. Try redefining `f[x]` as `f[x_, p_ ] := x^2 * p[[1]].`

Comment: I have tried that already, and it did not work for me.

Comment: It worked for me. Try quitting your kernel, redefining `f` as I have shown above, and do `Manipulate[Plot[f[x, p], {x, 0, 1}], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]`.

Comment: I think i might have left some important information.
the term i'd like to work with is the solution to a DSolve, which means 
it might be treated a bit differently with respect to p[[1]]

Comment: you are right, but my term is computed through a process which may change it a bit.


eq = {y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y[p[[1]]] == p[[2]]};
sol = DSolve[eq, y, x]
f[x_, p_] := y[x] /. sol[[1]]
f[x, p]
Manipulate[Plot[f[x, p]
  , {x, 0, p[[1]]}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]

This is a simple example of my problam.

Comment: Here [check this out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQPkI.gif).

Comment: All right, the same sort of fix will work. Please edit your post with the new information.

Comment: I edited the post,
hope its a bit more clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Probably better to wrap everything up in one neat package:

```
f[t_, p_] := y[t] /. First@DSolve[{y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y[p[[1]]] == p[[2]]}, y, x]
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[t, p], {t, 0, p[[1]]}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1],
 {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}
]
```

Even simpler:

```
f[t_, p_] := DSolveValue[{y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y[p[[1]]] == p[[2]]}, y[t], x]
```

**OP**

A quick fix is to automatically scope all of the variables by defining all of these things as functions, essentially:

```
eq[p_] := {y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y[p[[1]]] == p[[2]]};
sol[p_] := DSolve[eq[p], y, x]
f[t_, p_] := y[t] /. sol[p][[1]]

Manipulate[
 Plot[f[t, p], {t, 0, p[[1]]}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1],
 {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}
]
```

[image]

Comment: It works!
Thank you so much for the time, you really put an effort!

Comment: I seem to have another issue, u might notice the plotting is done pretty slowly. I think it is because 'f[t,p]' is defined with 'p[[1]],p[[2]]', though it considers p to be a scaler, not a point, and give rise to the error 'Part::partd: "Part specification p[[1]] is longer than depth of object."'
when I again simply copy the function 'f[t,p]' and paste it into the plot, it is a lot faster.

Comment: @Guy. I'm not really understanding what you mean. It works fine for me, and it's also quick, as shown in the gif (which is real-time). Did you copy-and-paste my code exactly?  (There is a new version which you can see in the updated post.) Did you `ClearAll[f]` before defining `f` in the new way? Maybe you need to quit the kernel and try again?

Comment: For instance, if I define `f[t_,p_] := t^(3/2)*p[[2]]/p[[1]]^(3/2)`
and plot as such: 
`Manipulate[Plot[f[t, p], {t, 0, p[[1]]},PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],{{p{1,1}},Locator}]`
it will not update as smoothly as if I simply write:
`Manipulate[Plot[t^(3/2)*p[[2]]/p[[1]]^(3/2), {t, 0, p[[1]]},PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],{{p{1,1}},Locator}]`

Comment: @Guy. Well, that sounds like it's either version or OS dependent, because both of those run the same on my machine (V10.0.1 Mac Air OS 10.10.5) (once you fix the `{{p{1, 1}}, Locator}`, changing it to `{{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}`).

Comment: Well anyway, thank you so much, i really appreciate it